# Using TimeManager in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I'm using QGIS 3.4.1 and TimeManager 3.0.2.

I've tried every combination that I've seen suggested and still cannot get a working animation.  Started w/ a CSV import, saved to an ESRI shapefile.  All the data was brought in as a String.  I've since created new fields of both Date and Integer and copied over the date data into those columns and tried using each as the Start Time option in TM.  Also, I've formatted the date as YYYY-MM-DD.

Are there any issues w/ the version combination I have for QGIS and TM?

Comment: There are no known issues. Try with the latest version https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/version/3.2.1/ and provide sample data to reproduce this issue if it persists